# What is the <macro> tag in android xml file

Tags: android, android-resources

I was looking at some attributes references in the material design library and I stubled upon the `<macro>` tag.

Quick example found in the `res/values` of `com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0` lib:

```xml
<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>
<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_label_text_type">?attr/textAppearanceLabelLarge</macro>
```

I cannot find documentation about it in the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources).
I searched in the [XLIFF](https://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/xliff-core/v2.1/xliff-core-v2.1.html) specification too and the word macro do not appears. Still, Android studio recognised it and allow me to write it in the `<resources>` tag.

What is the `<macro>` tag ? How/when should it be used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`macro` is a form of constant definition.

`<macro>` is not official property in Android resources.

*For you*

```
m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape
```

to this value

```
?attr/shapeViewCornerSmall
```

This value has been assigned.

Comment: Do you know the actual benefit over normal attributes references ?

Comment: I can think of adding logic to macros. For example, implementation has been added. https://github.com/search?q=%3Cmacro+language%3Axml&type=code